# Получить переменную из AJAX в php файл

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Здравсвуйте. Обыскал весь интернет, ничего конкретного на мой вопрос не нашёл. Нужно создать переменную в jQuery Ajax и использовать его в качестве PHP переменного. Вот код, который я пробовал, ничего не вышло.
Вот код jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".table_info td a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = $(this).text();
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://myproject/pages/admin.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({fname: name}),
        dataType: "html",
        success: console.log("1")
      });
    });
});
```

Вот фрагмент кода PHP

```
<?php echo $_POST['fname']; ?>
```

Comment: А где отображается результат вывода кода PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в тот же ajax-запрос добавить вывод полученного из php-скрипта значения в какой-нибудь элемент страницы или в ту же консоль. Для этого свойству `success` присваивается функция обратного вызова с параметром `data`, который представляет полученные от скрипта данные:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".table_info td a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = $(this).text();
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://myproject/pages/admin.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({fname: name}),
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
});
```